# How to load .csv files in Matlab from the second row?

Tags: matlab

I need to load in Matlab .csv files from the second row inside a loop:

```
  for j=1:N
        "load A_j.csv from the second row"
        ....
    end
```

The file A_j.csv looks like

```
id1 id2 id3
1   4   1
2   5   0
2   6   1
```

I don't know a priori the number of rows of each `A_j.csv` file. Any suggestion? I want to load from the second row because the first row of each `A_j.csv` is a "string".

Comment: Why not load the whole CSV and then select the second row using MATLAB's index notation?

Comment: The first row is a "name"

Comment: what is the exact problem? loading a specific file name? which "row" are you referring to? give more details

Answer (score 3):

**Pass an extra argument to `csvread`**.

If you look at the documentation for [csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html), it states:

> `M = csvread(filename,R1,C1)` reads data from the file starting at row
>   offset R1 and column offset C1. For example, the offsets R1=0, C1=0
>   specify the first value in the file.

So, you can use an offset of 1 for the row and 0 for the column.

Comment: It does not work: the A_j.csv file has three columns; if j=1 and I type M = csvread('A_1.csv',1,0) it gives me a column vector of size (size(A_1,2)-1)x1. I don't understand why. It seems that it vectorises each row until it reaches (size(A_1,2)-1)

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowing more about your `csv` file.

Comment: I have copied a section of the csv file.